# Displaying the assigned value in the MySQL DB in a select tag

Tags: php, mysql

when I'm displaying a user info, it has roles. God and Pesant. The code looks like this:

```
<td>
  <select name='' id='' class='form-control'>
    <option value='god'>God</option>
    <option value = 'pesant'>Pesant</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

When i'm displaying this info, how can I call from MySQL DB to show the value that is assigned to it? Right now it will always show God to everyone, and if I press Save, it saves the admin aka God mode to everyone.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the values that you were getting from database as

```
<option value='god' <?php echo ($value === 'god') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>God</option>
<option value ='pesant' <?php echo ($value === 'pesant') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Pesant</option>
```

This'll check that the values that you were getting from database matches with option value if `yes` then it'll place `selected` attribute else `''`

Answer (score 0):

Check & add `selected` attribute

```
<option value='god' <?php echo ($value == 'god') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>God</option>
<option value ='pesant' <?php echo ($value == 'pesant') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Pesant</option>
```

Assuming `$value` will contain the value from database. If have run a query and fetch the value from database.